# "come" vs. "come along" in a specific context

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Would you please tell me if there any difference in meaning between *come* and *come along* in the context below.

> We were having a party, but not many people **came** because of the bad weather.
>
> We were having a party, but not many people **came along** because of the bad weather.

Dictionaries define both *come* and *come along* to mean arrive at a place, so going by them they mean the exact same thing. Dictionaries don't always explain nuances, so I'd like to know if there is a nuance of difference in meaning between the two in the context.

Comment: The short answer is that only *came* is really correct here, but the nuance of why "came long" to mean "arrive" isn't really correct is difficult to explain.  I think you might need to consult a better dictionary, though, because *come/come along* don't mean exactly the same thing; see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come-along for example.

Comment: Agree. I think M-W #3 is kind of what you're going for here, but "come along" in that sense isn't always idiomatic. Doesn't seem to work very well in the negative.

Comment: What dictionary defines "come along" as "arrive at a place"?

Comment: @gotube: this one https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-along and this one

Comment: Also, a book called "English Phrasal Verbs in Use" by Micheal McCarthy and Felicity O'Dell on the page (page 16) for the phrasal "come along" they give this example: "Not many people bought tickets for the concert in advance, but quite a few came along and bought tickets at the door."

Comment: @strangdon Given all this I can't figure out why "come along" doesn't sound good. I'd really appreciate it if someone explained to me why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence isn't correct.

To "come along" has some nuanced meanings, none of which apply to arriving at a party. One is "*randomly happen to* arrive at a place", and another is "arrive at a place *with someone else or where someone else is*"

The six examples at cambridge.org fit into these two meanings:

randomly happen to arrive at a place:

> You wait half an hour for a bus, then three come along at once!
> We were just standing talking when Jamie came along.
> Pete came along in his car and offered us a lift.
> I was waiting at the airport when who should come along but Mr Pettigrew!

arrive at a place with someone else:

> Go now and I'll come along later.
> We're going to the swimming pool - you can come along later if you want.

Neither meaning applies to your example sentence because it doesn't make sense to say either that people *didn't randomly happen to arrive* at the party due to the weather, or that people *didn't arrive with other people* due to the weather.